CSS sticky header jittering when scroll position changes
I'm experiencing an issue with the CSS sticky property on a header element. When the header transitions from its initial fixed position to sticky, it starts to jitter or shake as I scroll to a specific position. This makes the user experience quite unpleasant.
Initially, the header was set to position: fixed; and everything worked smoothly.
I changed the header's position to sticky using position: -webkit-sticky; position: sticky; to improve the layout.
The problem occurs when the header becomes sticky at a certain scroll position.
I expected the header to remain smooth and stable during the transition from fixed to sticky. However, instead, it jitters or shakes noticeably.
.header-fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  transition: position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.header-sticky {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition: position 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

const headerStyles = cva("w-full h-[52px] flex items-center justify-between", {
  variants: {
    backgroundColor: {
      transparent: "bg-transparent header-fixed z-[900]",
      white: "bg-white shadow-area-card header-sticky h-[52px] z-[900]",
    },
    titleAlign: {
      left: "justify-start",
      center: "justify-center",
    },
  },
  defaultVariants: {
    backgroundColor: "white",
    titleAlign: "center",
  },
});

tsx code


 <MainLayout
      headerProps={{
        backgroundColor: inView ? "transparent" : "white",
        title: inView ? "" : area?.krName!,
        titleAlign: "center",
        rightIcons: [
          {
            icon: inView ? ICON.shareArea.white : ICON.shareArea.black,
            alt: "share",
            size: 20,
            onClick: () => {},
          },
        ],
      }}
    >
      {area && (
        <main className="h-full w-full relative container">
          <div ref={ref}>
            <CardImgFrame
              imageUrl={area.imageUrl}
              alt={area.title}
              frameClassName="-z-50 -mb-11 aspect-4/5"
              imageClassName="object-cover"
              isTop={true}
              country={area.info.location[0]}
              city={area.info.location[1]}
              areaName={area.name}
            />
          </div>
          <section className="w-full h-full p-4 pb-0">
            <div className="w-full h-full bg-white rounded-t-lg">
              <AreaDetailCard
                area={area}
                reviewSectionRef={reviewSectionRef}
                ratingAmount={areaReviews?.length || 0}
              />
              <Tab
                TABS={TABS.areaDetail}
                currentTab={currentTab!}
                setCurrentTab={setCurrentTab}
                frameClassName="top-[56px] shadow-area-section"
              />
              <div
                ref={(tabEl) => {
                  sectionRefs.current[0] = tabEl;
                }}
                className="mb-3 w-full h-full rounded-lg shadow-area-section"
              >
                <NoticeForm area={area} />
              </div>
              <div
                ref={(tabEl) => {
                  sectionRefs.current[1] = tabEl;
                }}
                className="mb-3 w-full h-full rounded-lg shadow-area-section"
              >
                <LocationForm area={area} />
              </div>
              <div
                ref={(tabEl) => {
                  sectionRefs.current[2] = tabEl;
                  reviewSectionRef.current = tabEl;
                }}
                className="mb-3 w-full h-full rounded-lg shadow-area-section"
              >
                <ReviewSummaryCard
                  areaName={area.krName!}
                  rating={area.rating!}
                  ratingAmount={areaReviews?.length || 0}
                  areaId={areaId}
                />
                {areaReviews &&
                  areaReviews
                    .sort(
                      (a, b) =>
                        new Date(b.createdAt).getTime() -
                        new Date(a.createdAt).getTime()
                    )
                    .map((review, idx) => {
                      return (
                        <AreaReviewCard
                          key={idx}
                          userImageUrl={user?.user_metadata.profileImg}
                          name={user?.user_metadata.nickname}
                          imageUrl={review.imageUrls[0]}
                          createdAt={review.createdAt}
                          rating={review.rating!}
                          description={review.content!}
                          reviewInfo={review}
                        />
                      );
                    })}
              </div>
            </div>
            <UnderBar area={area} />
          </section>
        </main>
      )}
    </MainLayout>





Could please show your full code? Maybe as a stack snippet if possible. What browser(s) are you using?

i add images and codes
sorry i don't know well code snippet is it right?
and i'm using Chrome browser

The jittering issue with your sticky header likely comes from the transition property on the position. CSS doesn't allow transitions on the position property because changing between fixed, sticky, or absolute is a binary switch and can't be smoothly animated. This might cause the flickering or jittery behavior you're experiencing when the header changes from fixed to sticky.
